# Angular 9 DatePipe: How to ignore timezone format

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, timezone, angular-pipe

I am currently using angular 9 DateTime Pipe in order to format my dateTimes.
I am storing the dateTimes in database with DataTimeOffset.
When I am retrieving this dates from server are in this form: "2021-03-30T16:26:52.047+02:00"

I am using this code to apply the format to my dates:

```
const pipe = new DatePipe('en-Us);
const formatedDate = pipe.transform(date, 'dd.MMM.yyyy HH:mm:ss');
```

When I am doing this, the pipe is taking the browser time and format my date.
I know that this is the default option, if I am not sending the 3rd parameter to the transform function.

But I have a business need to show the dates as they are...but formatted in the format mentioned above,

My question is: How can I avoid the timeZone convert but still format the dateTime?

Comment: How about a quick fix using `String#split`: `pipe.transform(date.split('+')[0], 'dd.MMM.yyyy HH:mm:ss');`

Comment: Well, first of all, this is pretty dirty :) And secondly if the timezone will be with "-" you need to handle that case also.

Comment: Working with plain old javascript date objects will always be painful when it comes to timezones as there a lot of nuances. Honestly, try moving to moment.js and write a custom pipe for handling moment objects. Most of people that do never look back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many days of investigation, the only workaround was to use the library "Luxon".

https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/zones.html

With this library I can do something like this:

```
var keepOffset = DateTime.fromISO("2017-05-15T09:10:23-09:00", { setZone: true });
```

Which will keep the offset intact.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `var transformedDate = new Date(datepipe.transform(myDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd' + ' UTC'))`